# Win 03 Server process agent.exe consuming 100% cpu

Tags: central-processing-unit, agent

i've have a win 03 server which periodically slows to a crawl and when i hit the task manager i can see 2 instances of agent.exe consuming 49% each of the CPU

how do i get rid of this process or at least stop it from consuming so much of the CPU?
actually, what the heck is agent.exe anyway!

Answer (score 2):

That really doesn't strike me as being a part of Windows. I'd wager that it's third-party software. That name is generic enough that it's going to be hard to guess what it might be, though.

You can use something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to get the path of the program on the disk, or you may get luck by doing a `dir C:\agent.exe /s /a /b` and seeing what comes back.

Hopefully either the path of the program or embedded version information in the EXE (visible on the "Properties" sheets in Windows Explorer) will tell you more about what it is.

Comment: Good advice. Find the executable, look at the version information on the file properties, determine what it is and if it's needed, then troubleshoot why it's behaving the way it is.